# $elemMatch projection in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
dbo.collection("users")
            .findOne({email: emailGiven, "friends.email": element.email},
                     { friends: { $elemMatch: { email: element.email } } },
                     function(errT, resultT) {})
```

I have the query above in node.js but for some reason the query's elemMatch part doesn't work on node.js but when I execute  the same query in mongo terminal it works, so I'm thinking maybe node.js doesn't support $elemMatch? If this is the case, could anyone tell me what would be the equivalent of this query in node.js?

Sample data from my DB:

```
/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad20cef8248544860ce3dc1"),
    "username" : "test",
    "email": "",
    "fullName" : "",
    "friends" : [{email: "",
                 status :""}],
    "alarms": [ {"id":111,
        "title": "TITLE",
        "location": "",
        "startTime": "10-10-1996 10:18:00",
        "endTime": "10-10-1996 10:18:00" }, {},{}

    ],
     "pnumber" : ""
}
```

Comment: _elemMatch part doesnt work on node.js_, do you see any error or what ?

Comment: No errors its just returning the query that would have been returned if elemMatch wasnt there at the first place

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50069207/6804958) answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The node.js driver [`findOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#findOne) has a different call signature than the `findOne` in the MongoDB shell. You pass the field selection object as the `projection` element of the `options` parameter:

```
dbo.collection("users")
    .findOne({"friends.email": email}, 
             {projection: { friends: { $elemMatch: { email: email } } } },
             function(errT, resultT) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks... I was searching this throughout the day. Working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `find` for any values which is stored in some variable, you use `regex` for that. Your query should look like

```
dbo.collection("users").findOne({
    email: new RegExp(emailGiven, 'i'),
    "friends.email": new RegExp(element.email, 'i')
}, {
    friends: {
        $elemMatch: {
            email: new RegExp(element.email, 'i')
        }
    }
}, function(errT, resultT) {})
```

`i` is for case insensitive comparison here

Comment: how to do this with more fields, like a $OR operator?